# Как упростить конструкцию на PHP?

Tags: php, html, база-данных, ооп, mysqli

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  include ('connect.class.php');

  $db = new Database;

$ins = array(
        'type_product' => $_POST['type_product'],
        'company_product' => $_POST['company_product'],
        'color_product' => $_POST['color_product'],
        'line_product' => $_POST['line_product'],
        'bend_product' => $_POST['bend_product'],
        'thickness_product' => $_POST['thickness_product'],
        'long_product' => $_POST['long_product'],
        'unit_of_measure_product' => $_POST['unit_of_measure_product'],
        'price_product' => $_POST['price_product'],
        'mix_product' => $_POST['mix_product'],
        'quantity_product' => $_POST['quantity_product'],
        'lines_product' => $_POST['lines_product'],
        'size_product' => $_POST['size_product'],
        'composition_product' => $_POST['composition_product'],
        'description_product' => $_POST['description_product']
);

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      if (is_array($ins))
      {
          $db->insert('product', $ins);
      }
  }
  ?>


  <form method="post">
<?php
foreach($ins as $key => $value)
    {
    echo  '<input type="text" name="' . $key . '" required>';
    }
?>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Самая главная ошибка - никогда, НИКОГДА не передавайте в БД сразу из ввода (POST, GET, UI...). Возможно, метод `insert` и содержит внутреннюю проверку, но сомневаюсь. На первых порах можно пользоваться встроенными escape-рами, но лучше поменять подход к обработке данных

Answer (score 0):

Например, сначала просто определить массив нужных полей, затем заполнить их из `$_POST`, и передать дальше. проверять что `$ins` это массив смысла нет, вы его именно так и определили.

```
$fields = [ 'type',  'company',  'color', 'line', 'bend',  'thickness', 'long', 'unit_of_measure',
            'price', 'mix', 'quantity',  'lines',  'size', 'composition',  'description',
        ];


$data = [];
foreach($fields as $field){
    $k = "{$field}_product";
    $data[$k] = isset($_POST[$k]) ? $_POST[$k] : null;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $db->insert('product', $data);
}
```

Comment: $data = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_fill_keys($field, true));

Comment: @splash58 если в POST будут не все поля, то и в результирующем массиве будут не все. но в целом я тоже хотел написать  нечто подобное вначале, но подходящей функции так и не нашел, чтобы в результирующем массиве были только нужные ключи. и да, лучше `null` а не `false` уж тогда.

Comment: а если в пост предполагаются не все ключи, то ваш код `$data[$k] = $_POST[$k];` - это ошибка

Comment: @splash58 да, нужна проверка наличия ключа.